# flutter speech_to_text example SpeechRecognitionError

Tags: flutter, speech-to-text

I'm trying to run `speech_to_text` example project ([here](https://github.com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/tree/main/speech_to_text/example)) on my phone for an another project. I'm clone the least version and only update these lines:

```
path: speech_to_text/example/android/build.gradle

line 2: ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

```
path: speech_to_text/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

line 14: android:name="${applicationName}"
```

Also I didn't change any permissions on AndroidManifest.xml. ([reference](https://github.com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/blob/fd50581c6e37b9f7b734965881eacdcd2eb915f9/speech_to_text/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L3))

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

And application installed clearly, there is no problem. But when I want to `start` recognition in application, application writes to screen `error_permission - true` like this.

[image: flutter permission error]

Here is error log:

```
I/flutter (27860): 2022-02-21T00:43:41.721954 start listening
D/SpeechToTextPlugin(27860): Start listening
D/SpeechToTextPlugin(27860): setupRecognizerIntent
D/SpeechToTextPlugin(27860): Notify status:listening
D/SpeechToTextPlugin(27860): Start listening done
D/SpeechToTextPlugin(27860): Error 9 after start at 5 1000.0 / -100.0
D/SpeechToTextPlugin(27860): Notify status:notListening
D/SpeechToTextPlugin(27860): Notify status:doneNoResult
I/flutter (27860): 2022-02-21T00:43:41.829552 Received listener status: listening, listening: true
I/flutter (27860): 2022-02-21T00:43:41.834224 Received listener status: notListening, listening: false
I/flutter (27860): 2022-02-21T00:43:41.835629 Received listener status: done, listening: false
I/flutter (27860): 2022-02-21T00:43:41.837419 Received error status: SpeechRecognitionError msg: error_permission, permanent: true, listening: false
```

I'm very new to flutter and I don't know which I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: have you add internet permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: @HeIsDying already exists in `AndroidManifest.xml` and I did not change it

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't work on the eumulator. try on your real device.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).